# Guessing Game - Prompt the user to play again

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a guessing game, but I want to add another line of code where the user can play again after, but I don't know where to start.

```
print ("Welcome to the Number Guessing Game in Python!")

# Initialize the number to be guessed
number_to_guess = 7

# Initialize the number of tries the player has made
count_number_of_tries = 1

# Obtain their initial guess
guess = int (input ("Please guess a number between 1 and 10: "))
while number_to_guess != guess:
    print ("Sorry wrong number!")
              
    # Check to see they have not exceeded the maximum number of attempts if so break out of loop
    if count_number_of_tries == 3:
        break
    elif guess < number_to_guess:
        print ("Your guess was lower than the number.")
    else:
        print ("Your guess was higher than the number.")

    # Obtain their next guess and increment number of attempts
    guess = int(input ("Please guess again: "))
    count_number_of_tries += 1

# Check to see if they did guess the correct number
if number_to_guess == guess:
    print ("Well done you won!")
    print ("You took" + str(count_number_of_tries) + "attempts to complete the game.")
else:
    print ("Sorry, you lose")
    print ("The number you needed to guess was " + str(number_to_guess) + "." )

print ("Game Over.")
```

I dont know if the code should be at the bottom or in between somewhere.
I also want to remove the break if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great idea! In my mind, there are two ways of continuously asking the user to play until they enter something that will let you know they want to stop like 'q', 'quit', or 'exit'. First you could nest all of your current code a while loop *(indent and write 'while(): before the code)*, or turn your current code into a function, and call it over and over again until the user enters the *exit* command

Ex:
lets say i can print hello world like this

```
# your game here
```

but now I want to keep printing it until the user enters 'quit'

```
user_input = '.' # this char does not matter as long as it's not 'quit'
while user_input != 'quit': # check if 'user_input' is not 'quit'
    # your game here

    user_input = input('Press any key to continue (and enter) or write "quit" to exit: ') # prompt user to enter any key, or write quit
```

Comment: Um if I'm being honest I have no idea what that means.

Comment: I create a variable called user_input and initialize it as '.' although it could be any string.  In the next line (*while user_input != 'quit':*) I am saying while user_input is not 'quit' keep repeating what is indented 
The next line (# your game here) you would replace with your code you already have (above) for your game
And the last line I ask for the user to input some text through the terminal and set that text to user_input, so now if the user types 'quit' and presses enter the program will go to the while loop and check if user_input is 'quit' (which it now is) and then not repeat.

Comment: I created a repl so you can see what I mean
https://replit.com/@JacobNoahGlik/Example-code-for-Blossom

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it, just a basic while loop

```py
playAgain = 'y'
while playAgain == 'y':
    print ("Welcome to the Number Guessing Game in Python!")
    # Initialize the number to be guessed
    number_to_guess = 7
    # Initialize the number of tries the player has made
    count_number_of_tries = 1
    # Obtain their initial guess
    guess = int (input ("Please guess a number between 1 and 10: "))
    while number_to_guess != guess:
              print ("Sorry wrong number!")
              
    # Check to see they have not exceeded the maximum number of attempts if so break out of loop
              if count_number_of_tries == 3:
                  print("You've guessed more than three times, you're pretty bad")
              elif guess < number_to_guess:
                         print ("Your guess was lower than the number.")
              else:
                         print ("Your guess was higher than the number.")
    # Obtain their next guess and increment number of attempts
              guess = int(input ("Please guess again: "))
              count_number_of_tries += 1
    # Check to see if they did guess the correct number
    if number_to_guess == guess:
         print ("Well done you won!")
         print ("You took " + str(count_number_of_tries) + " attempts to complete the game.")
    else:
        print ("Sorry, you lose")
        print ("The number you needed to guess was " + str(number_to_guess) + "." )
    print ("Game Over.")
    playAgain = (input ("Type y to play again, otherwise press enter: "))
print("Goodbye gamer")
```

Comment: What if the user didn't want to play again and it shows a goodbye message and maybe remove the break after if count_number_of_tries == 3: How would that look?

Comment: I just edited, removing the break just allows for infinite guesses, then pressing enter will exit the program

Answer (score 0):

Put all of that code in a game() function.
Underneath, write

```
while True:
    game()
    play=int(input('Play again? 1=Yes 0=No : '))
    if play == 1:
        pass
    else:
        break

print("Bye!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a while loop to the outermost layer that randomly generates the value of `number_to_guess` on each startup. And ask if you want to continue at the end of each session.

```py
import random

print("Welcome to the Number Guessing Game in Python!")

number_range = [1, 10]
inp_msg = "Please guess a number between {} and {}: ".format(*number_range)
while True:
    # Initialize the number to be guessed
    number_to_guess = random.randint(*number_range)
    # Initialize the number of tries the player has made
    count_number_of_tries = 1
    # Obtain their initial guess
    guess = int(input(inp_msg))
    while number_to_guess != guess:
        print("Sorry wrong number!")

        # Check to see they have not exceeded the maximum number of attempts if so break out of loop
        if count_number_of_tries == 3:
            break
        elif guess < number_to_guess:
            print("Your guess was lower than the number.")
        else:
            print("Your guess was higher than the number.")
        # Obtain their next guess and increment number of attempts
        guess = int(input("Please guess again: "))
        count_number_of_tries += 1
    # Check to see if they did guess the correct number
    if number_to_guess == guess:
        print("Well done you won!")
        print("You took" + str(count_number_of_tries) + "attempts to complete the game.")
    else:
        print("Sorry, you lose")
        print("The number you needed to guess was " + str(number_to_guess) + ".")

    if input("Do you want another round? (y/n)").lower() != "y":
        break
print("Game Over.")
```